# How to insert data to remote mysql server from another location using php

Tags: mysql

I need to insert data to remote mysql server from another location using PHP
how to make connection on mysql.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.55", "root", "", "sdh_extension");
```

this connection is not recognize.

Comment: The IP address your using is a local one, one which may be used for virtual machines etc.  If you try this from a remote machine it won't know how to connect to this address.

Comment: @NigelRen, there are two machine in LAN so i need to insert data from one database to another using PHP this is my requirement. how can i do it?

Comment: Can you 'ping' the IP address from that server?

Comment: yes i can. i allow the remote access also using my.ini file

Comment: two machine are in same LAN. and one has a mysql server i need to connect mysql database from another computer that also has mysql server. one computer to another is pinging properly. but mysql connection is not working..any one have solution

Comment: I got solve this. thanks @Nigel Ren